# Server Ping with iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, networking, ping

I'm writing an app that needs to know which of two servers responds fastest.  One server is in my time zone, the other is far away.

**How do I get the round trip time from a server ping on the iPhone?**

I looked at Reachability, and I don't think it does what I need in this case.  Alternate solutions are welcome as well.  Thanks!

Comment: If you need physical location you can get that directly from the phone, wouldn't that be better?

Comment: In some ways, yes.  One consideration we have is traffic.  If one server is responding more slowly, we might want to route them to our other server.  I don't know how common this is, and I admit this is mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: well you need to decide which it is. If it's response time, physical distance is irrelevant, you need to time a ping of some sort. If it's physical distance, use the GPS.

Comment: I got some clarification - we will be mirroring the servers, so response time is what we care about.

Comment: Why not look at using a load balancer? Ping does not tell the whole story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this implementation of [ping - source](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/2417/download.aspx)

Or, Apple has an example App you can look at - [SimplePing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html)

Another option is to use an existing lib: http://www.kernelthread.com/projects/hanoi/html/icmp.html

Comment: SimplePing was what I was looking for!  Thanks!