# How to Ping or check if server of particular IP Address is available/connected in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ip-address

I want to Ping or Lookup a particular IP address of server if it is connected or available at that particular time or not in my iPhone application.

I searched a lot over internet but could not find any relevant result for same.

Please help me as I am new to this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server Ping with iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720485/server-ping-with-iphone)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apple provides reachability classes you can use the class and

You can download [reachability.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5) and [Reachability.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5)

And use this as

```
Reachability* reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

netStatus gives the reachabilty of the server.

Comment: change  @"www.apple.com" to ip , say @"12.1.12.1"

Comment: also change to `reachabilityWithAddress`

Comment: Thanks for your reply...  It requires (const struct sockaddr_in *) as parameter. Can you please tell me how can I convert IP Address string to sockaddr_in. Thanks a lot..

Comment: this should help you `struct sockaddr_in callAddress;
 callAddress.sin_len = sizeof(callAddress);
 callAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
 callAddress.sin_port = htons(24);
 callAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("12.1.12.1");`

Comment: FYI - Reachability.m / .h can now be found here ( above links broken ):  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_9

Comment: From the document: A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host. So not really.

Comment: The reachability for host provided by Apple is a bit of a joke. The most charitable I can be is "it's horribly misnamed".

Answer (score 17):

If you want to ping the server, try this:

[SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

It allows for you to ping by either hostname or IP.

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS. `- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet sequenceNumber:(uint16_t)sequenceNumber` never gets called, even after adding `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>` to Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

You need Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) Sample Application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But code for Reachability checks for if Internet connection/WIFI is available or not, but there is no option for checking if server with particular IP Address which does not have host name is available or not. Please help.....

Comment: No...not necessarily. That's part of what it does.

Comment: It doesn't works it we put IP Address as it asks for host name not IP Address