# How can i detect which type of network iam using in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, crash

Is it possible to detect which type of network we are using like **wifi, DSL, very poor network** ?

Actually my app is crashing in **Very poor, 100% loss and high latency network**.

Is there any way to detect this so I can reduce the load with respect to network condition?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use to some extent Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

For example you can [ping a particular IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132827/how-to-ping-or-check-if-server-of-particular-ip-address-is-available-connected-i) and derive some metrics from the result

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't detect a quality of your connection. But there is a nice class `Reachability` which represents few useful methods to detect connection states.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Reachability.m. it'll tell you whether you have any connection, and then tell you what kind of connection you have. It tells every thing about network.

[Download Rechability here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can download the [Reachablity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class. and add the following to check network type

```
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability sharedReachability];
[reachability setHostName:@"www.google.com"];    // set your host name here
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability remoteHostStatus];

if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) {NSLog(@"no");}
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) {NSLog(@"wifi"); }
else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) {NSLog(@"cell"); }
```