# How can I detect vpn connection in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, vpn

I had developed an app required connected VPN to see the app content. My problem now, whenever user forgot to turn on VPN I need to show user alert box that remind user to connect to VPN to see the content once app opened (I think i need to implement this function in AppDelegate). How can I achieve this kind of situation? . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little helper to detect what you're looking for. This is the snippet:

```
struct VpnChecker {

    private static let vpnProtocolsKeysIdentifiers = [
        "tap", "tun", "ppp", "ipsec", "utun"
    ]

    static func isVpnActive() -> Bool {
        guard let cfDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() else { return false }
        let nsDict = cfDict.takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary
        guard let keys = nsDict["__SCOPED__"] as? NSDictionary,
            let allKeys = keys.allKeys as? [String] else { return false }

        // Checking for tunneling protocols in the keys
        for key in allKeys {
            for protocolId in vpnProtocolsKeysIdentifiers
                where key.starts(with: protocolId) {
                // I use start(with:), so I can cover also `ipsec4`, `ppp0`, `utun0` etc...
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Usage: `VpnChecker.isVpnActive()`

I also wrote a little blog post about it [here](https://medium.com/@alessandrofrancucci/checking-vpn-connection-on-ios-swift-9748d733e49d)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to connect to a specific site or IP address via the VPN, right?  You can simply use Reachability to detect whether the IP address is reachable, and [Apple sample code can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

More information can be seen in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886788/iphone-reachability-test-for-specific-ip-port) [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132827/how-to-ping-or-check-if-server-of-particular-ip-address-is-available-connected-i).

Comment: "You can simply use Reachability to detect whether the IP address is reachable" - no, you can't. Apple's host reachability doesn't actually test reaching the IP, it only tests the first hop (e.g. to local router). It's hopelessly misnamed.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the connection goes through VPN implement this code and call it everytime the user use the app so this must be handled in

`func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) { }`

or

`func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) { }`

```
func isVPNConnected() -> Bool {
    let cfDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()
    let nsDict = cfDict!.takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary
    let keys = nsDict["__SCOPED__"] as! NSDictionary

    for key: String in keys.allKeys as! [String] {
        if (key == "tap" || key == "tun" || key == "ppp" || key == "ipsec" || key == "ipsec0" || key == "utun1" || key == "utun2") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```