# How do I ping a server port with iOS 5 SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, ping

Basically, I want to check to see if a game server is online/offline but the server is hosted through a port, how would I go about pinging it to check this. For testing purposes the server I want to ping is `fr7.mooshroom.net:25667`, however eventually I will be importing the server IP and port from an online plist so could the ip address and port be separated

If you could give me a step by step guide on how to do this, that would be much appreciated.

I am using the `Reachability` by `tonymillion` because the apple one doesnt work with iOS 5.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720485/server-ping-with-iphone

Comment: None of them are for servers with ports. That is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it depends on if you are talking about TCP or UDP.

If it's TCP, then the answer may be simple: try to open a TCP connection to the server at that port.  If the connection opens, drop the connection and report success.  Otherwise, failure.  This is the simplistic view.  It's possible if there are load balancers or firewalls in front of the server, the TCP connection may open but the backend server is down.

UDP would be harder.  There is no way to know when you send UDP data that the server got the data unless it sends you some kind of response.  It's possible that if the UDP server is down and you sent a message to the port, your computer *might* get an ICMP Error message back.  That would definitely let you know the server is down.  But firewalls may block this message getting back to your device, so that might not be reliable.

Otherwise, you need to send a properly formatted message to the server to get some kind of response.  This is protocol-dependent but is the most reliable.

The traditional "ping" message is an ICMP echo query and response message.  As such, there is no "port" associated with ICMP.

Comment: Do you know if it possible to get the same individual packet details with TCP Ping using iOS SDK rather than just connection check?